# Can Proguard cause IPC issues between 2 Progauded applications?

Tags: android

I have many Applications in my project and those are somehow interconnected.Two applications app-A and app-B I have succesfully progurded.When I run proguarded app-A with unproguarded app-B it works fine but when I run both proguarded together I am not getting the results.

I have tried keeping the packages which are responsible for starting the important services but yet I am facing the same issue.
So,please help me regading this issue.Thanx in advance.
Here is a basic configuration I follow in my proguard-project.txt

```
# The official support library.

-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }


-libraryjars /libs/protobuf-java-2.3.0.jar
-libraryjars /libs/bcprov-ext-jdk15on-1.46.jar
-libraryjars /libs/google-java-oauth.jar
-libraryjars /libs/protoclasses.jar


  -dontwarn  org.bouncycastle**
  -dontwarn net.oauth.server**
  -dontwarn net.oauth.client**
  -dontwarn com.centerkey.utils**


  -keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
  -keep public class * extends android.app.Application
  -keep public class * extends android.app.Service
  -keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
  -keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
  -keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
  -keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper


 -keepattributes *Annotation*


   -keep public class com.intel.austonio.service** {
      public protected *;
   }

   -keep public class com.intel.austonio.sync** {
      public protected *;
   }



   #keep all public and protected methods that could be used by java reflection

  -keepclassmembernames class * {
       public protected <methods>;
   }

   -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
      native <methods>;
   }

  -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
     public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
   }

   -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
      public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
  }


  -keepclassmembers enum * {
      public static **[] values();
       public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
   }

   -keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
     public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
   }
```

Comment: Its Covid19 time in 2020 and I have exactly the same problem. Since 5 years have passed and no answer to this problem have appeared, I suppose its still a mystery.

Comment: Are you still facing the issue ? For me i found there were issues related to gson. Had to tell proguard not to obfuscate few classes. And it was resolved. You can ask you specific question , may be i could help !